Which type of patio door do I need to look for that is properly sealed, airtight and insulated but 36" wide?
I have a ~36x80 opening that goes into the patio/deck. The current door is just a pure joke: Normal indoor hinges and despite having some weather stripping, I can see the light (!) shining through the edges. The lower end has nothing except a simple "door sweep". Even with proper sealing, I feel this is not a proper exterior door as the seal can never be tight. Here is what it looks like:



This is the a view from the exterior:

I have looked at "Hinged patio doors" and "French doors" at the usual companies (Milgard, Jeld-Wen, Anderson, Marvin, Pella) but it seems all their patio doors start at 48" width.
I am looking for a proper door that has integrated seals which push against each other and provide maximum sealing (and insulation). Similar as a "tilt and turn window".
I have found this but it pretty much looks the same that what's already in there.
What do I even need to look for?

Can you show pics of the exterior?

This is basically what a modern door looks like. Yours needs adjustment and maintenance. Houses aren't static things. (You've asked an XY question.)

@Huesmann I have added a pic from the exterior (that's the best I have handy right now)

@isherwood Excuse my ignorance but are you sure a door like this can be properly sealed? In the same way as a new French patio door? This wall gets completely redone and there is "easy" opportunity to replace the door. Energy efficiency is pretty important to me but I was not able to find a new patio door that would fit this opening.

Well, I'm not sure what a "French" door is to you, but traditionally it has a lot of glass panels. That's not efficient to begin with. Then, energy lost through a door slab is a fairly minor thing compared to energy lost around it due to air leakage. Just buy a modern exterior door from a reputable manufacturer and don't stress over it. If it's installed and adjusted properly it'll be just fine, with no daylight showing.

Looking at the door in your pic, it appears that the door is not hung properly. The trim may need to be removed and the frame adjusted.
The top and side weatherstrips look to be the proper type for an exterior door. The bottom can have an additional sweep added such as a broom lip  or a full bottom.
The striker can be adjusted as well. This may need a little wood work done to move it outward to make the door close tighter.
You could call a local door expert and have them do the work. It would be much less than a new door.  Besides if a new door is not hung correctly, you will have the same issues.

I agree. The OP has some faulty assumptions and "feelings" that aren't accurate. This can be fixed.
